# EaselJS get direction on pressmove

Tags: createjs

I am trying to get the direction that the mouse is moving when using pressmove. On mousedown I get store the cursor coordinates values in the variables startX and startY, then on pressmove I check to see which side of startX and startY the mouse is. I would like to only get the general direction and not keep on jumping between the values as I am currently getting. So if the general direction is up then log 'up' and not 'up''left''up'etc.

```
 pressMove = function(event){
    var pt = this.globalToLocal(event.stageX, event.stageY);
    if(pt.x > this.startPosX){
        this.dragDirection = 'right';
    }

    if(pt.x < this.startPosX){
        this.dragDirection = 'left';
    }

    if(pt.y < this.startPosY){
        this.dragDirection = 'up';
    }

    if(pt.y > this.startPosY){
        this.dragDirection = 'down';
   }
   console.log(this.dragDirection)
}
```

Comment: You will be overwriting your left/right direction with up/down (so unless you move EXACTLY horizontal, your direction will always be "up" or "down".  It probably makes sense to store both values, and perhaps use a distance instead of a string.

Comment: @Lanny the point is to move the piece up, down, left, right and not allow it to move diagonally. How would storing the values be better off than using a string?

Comment: As long as you realize that once you move even one pixel down, you will never move horizontally. Typically, I would measure the distance the mouse has moved, and once it passes a threshold, then determine if they have moved horizontally or vertically. Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/65zzadvs/

Comment: @Lanny, that makes perfect sense and is what I was trying to achieve. I have worked on this a bit since this post. A couple of things stand out making startPos a global variable eliminated the need for me to have a point in both the mouseDown and pressMove functions. Math.max() and Math.abs() also help clean up the distance variable, previously I was getting a negative, thx.